# Website showing up as part of another domain on google

Tags: seo, google, subdomain, pagerank, subdirectory

**Background**

I have shared hosting with hostgator and have two domains on the hosting account. My primary domain which is metalbot.org and another domain with is twocan.co.

Each of these are separate websites: http://www.metalbot.org and https://twocan.co respectively.

When I type in 'TwoCan English', which is my main keyword for the second domain I get the following result!

[image]

Uh oh! That is not good at all...

**Questions**

why is my domain showing up as a sub-folder of my primary domain?

And my main question: How can I fix this so that when someone types in TwoCan English it shows https://twocan.co?

Comment: Well, that's exactly the content you have in http://www.metalbot.org/twocan_dev/ If you want to hide it, maybe add it to robots.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, it appears you didn't stop your dev folder to crawl by bots.

Do this and it should fix it.

Firstly, make sure your website works perfectly on your .co domain.

And then set a permanent 301 redirect in your .org domain (.org/two_can) to your primary .co domain. Meaning if you will fetch .org/two_can then it should redirect to the primary .co domain.

Leave this about for a week, you will see the incorrect will disappear from Google.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

If HostGator provides you with cPanel, login to it and add the second domain outside the main domain folder.  Then redirect it using its *index.php*.

Comment: This is a very short answer and not all that helpful.   Can you improve it by linking to HostGator documentation and providing the code needed to do the redirect in PHP?